# Imposing hierarchy on multiple columns, changing random number of column values based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset which contains the ID of the customers and indicators named 'WEEK1', 'WEEK2' etc. having value = 1 if the customer was enrolled in that particular week, otherwise 0, like below :

```
ID WEEK1 WEEK2 WEEK3 WEEK4 WEEK5
1   0     0     1     0     1
2   0     0     0     0     1
3   1     0     1     0     1
4   0     0     0     0     0
5   1     1     1     1     1
6   1     0     0     0     0
7   0     1     1     1     0
```

What I would like to do is search for the first week that customer was enrolled in, keep that week's indicator = 1 and change all the other week indicator values to 0 for that customer ID, i.e. O/P :-

```
ID WEEK1 WEEK2 WEEK3 WEEK4 WEEK5
1   0     0     1     0     0  ## WEEK5 is changed to 0 here
2   0     0     0     0     1  ## nothing changed
3   1     0     0     0     0  ## WEEK3 and WEEK5 is changed to 0
4   0     0     0     0     0
5   1     0     0     0     0
6   1     0     0     0     0
7   0     1     0     0     0
```

So for each customer ID, we find the first WEEK which has value = 1 and then put all the next WEEK values = 0.

Now I have tried this using if-else, putting each condition one by one like below :

```
if df['WEEK1'] == 1:
    df['WEEK2'] = 0
    df['WEEK3'] = 0
    df['WEEK4'] = 0
    df['WEEK5'] = 0
elif df['WEEK2'] == 1:
    df['WEEK3'] = 0
    df['WEEK4'] = 0
    df['WEEK5'] = 0
... and so on
```

using if-else worked for me when there were only 5 WEEK columns, but now I am getting data with 52 WEEK columns and I have not been able to find any alternative other than using if-else.

So anything which works for imposing hierarchy on these 5 columns and can also be extended to a variable number of columns like 52, 104 etc will be much helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#if first column is not index
df = df.set_index('ID')
df = df.where(df.shift(axis=1).eq(1).cumsum(axis=1).eq(0), 0)
print (df)
    WEEK1  WEEK2  WEEK3  WEEK4  WEEK5
ID                                   
1       0      0      1      0      0
2       0      0      0      0      1
3       1      0      0      0      0
4       0      0      0      0      0
5       1      0      0      0      0
6       1      0      0      0      0
7       0      1      0      0      0
```

**Details and explanation**:

First [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) values to right:

```
print (df.shift(axis=1))
    WEEK1  WEEK2  WEEK3  WEEK4  WEEK5
ID                                   
1     NaN    0.0    0.0    1.0    0.0
2     NaN    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
3     NaN    1.0    0.0    1.0    0.0
4     NaN    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
5     NaN    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
6     NaN    1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
7     NaN    0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
```

Compare by `1` if possible another values like `1` or `0`, else omit this step:

```
print (df.shift(axis=1).eq(1))
    WEEK1  WEEK2  WEEK3  WEEK4  WEEK5
ID                                   
1   False  False  False   True  False
2   False  False  False  False  False
3   False   True  False   True  False
4   False  False  False  False  False
5   False   True   True   True   True
6   False   True  False  False  False
7   False  False   True   True   True
```

Get cumulative sum per rows by [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
print (df.shift(axis=1).eq(1).cumsum(axis=1))
    WEEK1  WEEK2  WEEK3  WEEK4  WEEK5
ID                                   
1       0      0      0      1      1
2       0      0      0      0      0
3       0      1      1      2      2
4       0      0      0      0      0
5       0      1      2      3      4
6       0      1      1      1      1
7       0      0      1      2      3
```

Compare by `0`:

```
print (df.shift(axis=1).eq(1).cumsum(axis=1).eq(0))
    WEEK1  WEEK2  WEEK3  WEEK4  WEEK5
ID                                   
1    True   True   True  False  False
2    True   True   True   True   True
3    True  False  False  False  False
4    True   True   True   True   True
5    True  False  False  False  False
6    True  False  False  False  False
7    True   True  False  False  False
```

Last set values by mask `False` to `0` by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
print (df.where(df.shift(axis=1).eq(1).cumsum(axis=1).eq(0), 0))
    WEEK1  WEEK2  WEEK3  WEEK4  WEEK5
ID                                   
1       0      0      1      0      0
2       0      0      0      0      1
3       1      0      0      0      0
4       0      0      0      0      0
5       1      0      0      0      0
6       1      0      0      0      0
7       0      1      0      0      0
```